# How to retrieve date from sqlite database

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, date

My code is below. I want to get date within a string variable.

```
SQLiteCommand sqlite_cmd;
SQLiteDataReader sqlite_datareader;
SQLiteConnection sqlite_conn;

// create a new database connection:
sqlite_conn = new SQLiteConnection(sConnectionString);

// open the connection:
sqlite_conn.Open();

// create a new SQL command:
sqlite_cmd = sqlite_conn.CreateCommand();

//Check is there any project with the same information
sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "Select * from prework;";

try
{
    sqlite_datareader = sqlite_cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (sqlite_datareader.Read()) // Read() returns true if there is still a result line to read
    {
        // Print out the content of the text field:
        //String str = sqlite_datareader["date"].ToString();
        String str = Convert.ToDateTime(sqlite_datareader[4].ToString());
        MessageBox.Show(""+str);
    }
}
catch
{
    MessageBox.Show("error");
}

sqlite_conn.Close();
```

I want to take the date in a string variable. And then I will show date in a text box.